# Cordova Build error: nodeValue undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

After a couple of days without touching my app, today when I tried to build it I got the following error:

```
Error thrown while running shell command: "cordova build ios" 
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cordova build ios 
Error: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined
```

If I remove the ios platform and add it again, it will work, but that's not the best solution... I'd like to understand the issue.

Do you have any idea what might have caused this error and what would be the best solution to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any scripts running in build phase ?

Comment: No I don't have any script

Comment: where in your code r u doing "cordova build ios"  ?

Comment: The error above comes from `ember-cli-cordova` module. I get the error even if I run it manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I just got this exact same error. For me the cause was that in my MyApp-info.plist I had added a new line that was empty, basically there was a blank key-value pair like this:

```
<key></key>
<string></string>
```

Once I removed this, the error disappeared and cordova was able to build again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Major lifesaver! Anybody know why a new key and string suddenly appeared? Went to see Info in XCode and there was a new line that was empty for Key and Value

Comment: Huitling - were you ever editing the plist file in Xcode prior to that? If so - its possible you mistakingly added it without noticing. Thats how I found my extra line after not realizing what the issue was - its too easy to click on the + symbol in the Info settings view.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me in my react-native project. Don't know how it got there - but it crashed `react-native link` for me!

Comment: saved me at least 2 days of extra work for this stupid error.